# form_for should go to create in the controller but it doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

I am new to rails and just wrote a pretty complex for that updates the child elements of a video model I created.
The problem is, when I click the submit buttons it should go to the update function in the controller but instead it does nothing.
Here is my code:

```
<%= form_for :video, :url => video_path(@video), :html => { :method => 'put' } do |f| %>
.
.
.
    <p><%= submit_tag "Update video" %></p>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out what the problem was. In my routes file the rout for the video path was directing video/:id to a different location. after commenting that line it got to the update function.

Answer (score 0):

`:method => 'put'` is not `:html` option so try this:

```
<%= form_for :video, :url => video_path(@video), :method => 'put' do |f| %>
.
.
.
    <p><%= submit_tag "Update video" %></p>
<% end %>
```